# How to open one fragment as a Page from another fragment using button without activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using drawer navigation where all pages are fragments.How to open fragment page using button on another fragment ?

Comment: If you post the source code which you tried to implement this feature, people can guide you better.

Comment: Simply you can call fragment with `FragmentTransaction` and replace your fragment on button click.

Comment: #Devill i have already put example for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use FragmentManager like

call this method button onclick method

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

you have to replace you fragment manager id instead of `R.id.frame_container`

I hope this one will help to you :)

Comment: Thanks for your help but can u tell me how to find fragment manager id

Comment: Fragment manager id will be in xml file.It will shows only all fragment.check your current xml file :)

Comment: #Shri Panhale: Thanks a lot